# Dataflow flex template job attempts to launch second job (for pipeline) with same job_name

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to launch a Dataflow flex template. As part of the build and deploy process, I am pre-building a custom SDK container image to reduce worker start-up time.

I have attempted this in these ways:

1. When no `sdk_container_image` is specified and a requirements.txt file is provided, a Dataflow flex template is successfully launched and a graph is built, but the workers cannot start because they lack authority to install private packages.

- Errors:

  - Dataflow job appears to be stuck; no worker activity
  - Workers fail to install requirements

2. When an `sdk_container_image` is given (with dependencies pre-installed), the Dataflow job starts, but instead of running the pipeline on the same job, it attempts to launch a Dataflow job for the pipeline using the same name, which results in an error.

- Errors:

  - Duplicate Dataflow job name, DataflowJobAlreadyExistsError

3. If I attempt to pass a second job_name for the pipeline, the pipeline successfully starts in a separate job, but the original flex template job eventually fails due to a polling timeout. Pipeline fails at very last step due to sdk harness disconnected because "The worker VM had to shut down one or more processes due to lack of memory."

- Template errors:

  - Timeout in polling result file
- Pipeline Errors:

  - SDK harness disconnected (Out of memory)

4. When I launch the pipeline locally using DataflowRunner, the pipeline runs successfully under one job name.

Here are my Dockerfiles and `gcloud` commands:

Flex template Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python39-template-launcher-base

# Create working directory
ARG WORKDIR=/flex
RUN mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}
WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

# Due to a change in the Apache Beam base image in version 2.24, you must to install
# libffi-dev manually as a dependency. For more information:
#   https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/4891
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libffi-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY ./ ./

ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="${WORKDIR}/launch_pipeline.py"

# Install the pipeline dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir apache-beam[gcp]==2.41.0
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/google/dataflow/python_template_launcher" ]
```

Worker Dockerfile:

```
# Set up image for worker.
FROM apache/beam_python3.9_sdk:2.41.0

WORKDIR /worker

COPY ./requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

Building template:

```
gcloud dataflow flex-template build $TEMPLATE_LOCATION \
    --image "$IMAGE_LOCATION" \
    --sdk-language "PYTHON" \
    --metadata-file "metadata.json"
```

Launching template:

```
gcloud dataflow flex-template run ddjanke-local-flex \
    --template-file-gcs-location=$TEMPLATE_LOCATION \
    --project=$PROJECT \
    --service-account-email=$EMAIL \
    --parameters=[OTHER_ARGS...],sdk_container_image=$WORKER_IMAGE \
    --additional-experiments=use_runner_v2
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to solve this yesterday. The problem was that I was passing `sdk_container_image` to Dataflow through the flex template and then passing that through to the PipelineOptions within my code. After I removed `sdk_container_image` from the options, it launched the pipeline in the same job.